# Setting Up Independent Remote Desktop Network like Teamviewer

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

Recently I am Using two Software for Remote Desktop application.
1. Teamviewer ( For Personal Use)
2. RealVNC (For my business purpose)

For RealVNC, I need to configure routers all the time for remote sites. Also it requires static IP for connection.

For Teamviewer, they are using their own "Live Servers" for remote session, which are not permitted in my business application.

I want a solution which can establish remote session using:
1. My own Windows server.
2. Using custom generated ID & password (Like Teamviewer)

Is there any software which provide such service?
OR
Can somebody guide me to build application for same?

Comment: Product recommendations and app building are equally off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as simple as "create a ftp server and open a port then done", check out how teamviewer works [here](https://superuser.com/questions/661749/how-exactly-does-a-remote-program-like-team-viewer-work), sounds like you are working at a small business company, and this can't be done. Usually a medium or large enterprises company is under domain environment, so user can authenticate with DC to provide single sign-on experience, router is forming VPN tunnel to connect each site.

Comment: Teamviewer using RDP for Remote session. Also it is using central live server to generate ID & password for client & VPN tunnel establishment. Using my own server with static ip, I can also make VPN network & connect client. However We have to make track record of static IP address & password. We want single program which can run on my own server & provide id & password to clients can make this solution of problem. Related software I am not able to find.